# Rewrite for an empty query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm building in some caching to one of my sites, and I can't seem to find if there's a way to add a condition with mod_rewrite to apply only if the query string on a request is empty.

For example, I'd love to know if I can have a request with no query string like

```
http://www.example.com/
```

load the page at

```
http://www.example.com/index.home.html
```

But any request with a query string, such as

```
http://www.example.com/?id=32
```

to load normally and not be affected by the rewrite.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I figured it out. This seems to do the trick pretty well:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.home.html
```

Of course, if there's a better way, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: awesome thanks! really helped me in fixing a production issue.

Answer (score 5):

i know this ones pretty old, but better alternative is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} -n
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.home.html
```

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: The [documentation for mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) does not mention `-n` among the available tests for `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 3):

To match against empty QueryString , we use **^$** in our Condition Pattern. The following rule redirects **/file.html** to **/file2.html** but it fails to redirect **/file.html?querystring** because of the condition.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?file.html$ /file2.html? [L,R]
```

An empty question mark at the end of the Rule is important as it discards the old querystring otherwise the redirected url will look like **/file2.html?querystring** .

Or alternatively:
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?file.html$ /file2.html [L,R,QSD]
```

The QSD flag don't keep the query string if there is one.

Comment: If the RewriteCond filters out anything with a querystring, then how is including the question mark "important"?  No URL being rewritten will have a querystring to preserve.  Or am I misunderstanding?