# Set 404 to all url with params, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

i want to set 404 to all url with parameter (?), now its give 200 status code. How can I do it?
Example url with parameters:

https://www.google.com/?pomg

https://www.google.com/product/?spingoms

?spingoms  , ?pomg   - parameters

I want something like this - /?(.*) - [R=404,NC,L]
But everything i tried didn't work. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite for an empty query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630853/rewrite-for-an-empty-query-string) (it does the opposite, but all you need to do is negate the condition.)

Answer (score 1):

**This one works:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```